# "on" vs "regarding"

Tags: prepositions

A friend and I discussed the topic of career choices. In a follow-up letter to him, I am wondering if I should say:

> On the topic of career choices, I have had some new thoughts.

Or:

> Regarding the topic of career choices, I have had some new thoughts.

Which one looks more natural and correct?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second example, 'the topic of' is very much superfluous; 
'regarding' is more appropriate in your letter because you are replying *in regard to something*, whilst 'on the topic of' is more something one would say in a conversation, having actually just discussed that topic, directing it specifically to something else you want to talk about.
'Re the topic of career choices' would also be appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I need some clarification. Are you saying that  "regarding something" is more formal than "on something," as you said the former tends to be used on letters and the latter in conversations? If so, why do I see titles of essays such as "On Conversation" or "On Greedness" all the time? In that context (titles of essays), would it be better to say "Regarding Conversation?"

Comment: ‘On’ at the beginning of rulings and laws is more common than ‘regarding’ because it is specifically ‘on’ that topic—in an essay, the same applies. In a letter, you’re mentioning a topic, not dedicating a work to it, and so i’d say ‘on’ in your case would be more informal usage than ‘regarding’. The formality depends on the context; ‘regarding is generally more formal’, but isn’t used in the examples hereabove mentioned because of convention and its appropriateness for the application, not the register.

Comment: I think I read somewhere before that *on* is used for very specific and narrowed down topics.